# basic math question: transform a sum of exponents to a sum of logarithms

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I am sure this is a really dumb question but I am having trouble understanding it since I do not have any math background.

I have the logarithms of 2 values:

```
log(a) = 1347
log(b) = 1351
```

I am trying to calculate this:

```
exp( log(a) ) - exp( log(0.1) + log(b) )
```

I guess by transforming this into a sum/difference of logarithms and working in log scale because when I exponentiate the values become infinite. Basically I am looking for a solution for this in log scale, so that I do not get an Infinite value when entered in a calculator.

Does this make sense?

```
 log(a)-(0.1*log(b))
```

Thank you!

-fra

Comment: That is just $a / (0.1 \cdot b)$ by basic properties of logaritms. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I do not have a because I cannot solve for it since exp(log(a)) = Infinite. That is why I was looking to transform everything in log form.. is this correct: log(a)-(0.1*log(b)) ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Recall that $$\exp(\log(a))=a\quad\text{and}\quad\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y).$$ Here we're using the convention that the base of $\log$ is $e$.

Update: Using the first hint, we have $$\exp(\log a)=e^{1347}.$$ Combining the the second term of the equation, we have $$ \frac{1}{10}\exp(\log b)=\frac{1}{10}\exp({1351}).$$Now, combining the expressions, $$\exp(\log a)-\exp(\log(1/10)+\log(b))=e^{1347}-\frac{1}{10}e^{1351}.$$

Comment: Hi Clayton, thank you. I only have the log(a) though and if I try to exponentiate I get Inf…

Comment: @Francesca: Since we know $\log(a)=1347$, we can deduce that $$a=\exp(1347).$$ If you try to put this in a calculator, it surely will throw an error, but you can use this. Does clarify anything for you?

Comment: $@Francesca: I've updated the solution.

Comment: A yes, thank you very much!

Comment: If you like and understand the answer, feel free to accept it. If not, keep asking questions until you understand it clearly

Comment: My only problem is that I do need to get a number that is not Inf as a solution, so I was hoping to get a solution in log scale… IS this at all possible?

Comment: @Francesca Above is an exact answer that is certainly not infinity. Is this what you mean?

Comment: …not sure I understand then… If I try to enter this: exp(log(a)) - 0.1*exp(log(b)) in a calculator (I am using R) I get NaN… I must be missing something...

Comment: Maybe the question might have been clearer if stated like: How can I transform this: exp(log(a))-0.1*exp(log(b)) in a sum/difference of logarithms (since I cannot calculate the exp(log(a)) )?

Comment: @Francesca: You won't be able to compute it on a calculator because the number is ridiculously large, but it is _not_ infinity. Given a computer with enough capability, it could calculate this number precisely.

Comment: But do you think there is a way to make this: exp(log(a))-0.1*exp(log(b)) a sum of logarithms so that I don't actually have to compute any huge exponents? I was getting this: log(a) -log(0.1) - log(b), but this is wrong..

Comment: @Francesca: I don't think there is a way to simplify it any more... I'm not sure what else you're really asking about..

Comment: I would like to have only logs and no more exponential forms.

Comment: This seems right actually… log(a)-(0.1*log(b))